# Migration from .Net 6.0 To .Net 7 Automapper issues

Tags: startup, .net-7.0, automapper-12

Migration from .Net 6.0 To .Net 7 Automapper having issues in Startup.cs

```
 Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
 Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Reflection.Assembly' to 
 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AutoMapper.Profile>'
```

[image]

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lines of code to solve the problem:

```cs
services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Program)));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).